# how to interpret "if a in b in c and d" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some source codes that an old predecessor made with python2.

Now I have to fix it to run it in python3.

My questions are two.

1. What does mean `if a in b in c and d:`?
2. Is it possible in the specific case `if (list) in (str) in (list)` ?

Comment: afaik the second case will not work, at least in python 3, assuming `list` is a list sequence, `str` is a string

Comment: how about in python2? Does it also not working in python2?

Comment: what is it you are trying to do, and I checked it doesn't work in python 2 either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a in b in c` is a chained comparison

it is similar to this chained expression `a < b < c` which evaluates as `(a < b) and (b < c)`

putting all that together you get `(a in b) and (b in c) and d`

I'll note that that's very unlikely to be true though one example I can think of is `a = 'a'; b = 'ab'; c = 'abc'`

as for your second part it would be a type error always if `a` is a list